# borrowed value does not live long enough after reading line

Tags: rust

I'm trying to resize a vector of string using a string that a user enters from command line, but the compiler tells me that the variable, in which I store the string, is out of scope. Here is the code:

```
fn add_employee(h: &mut HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>>) {
    println!("Choose a department:");
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    for (key, value) in h {
        if key.to_string() == input {              // idk why but with input it works
            println!("Enter a name to add to this department:");
            let mut name = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut name)
                .expect("Failed to read line");
            value.resize(&value.len() + 1, &name); // here is where I get an error on the 
        }                                          // name variable saying it's out of scope
        input.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rust error messages contain a lot of useful information. Please read it! There are often hints how to fix the problem, or at least good explanations what's wrong. Given that you did not even quote the error accurately in this question, I assume you didn't pay a lot of attention to it, which is why I'm pointing this out. Please also include the full error message in this question.

Comment: Regarding your actual question, chances are you want the `HashMap` to own the strings in it, i.e. `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's not iterate the whole `HashMap` just to find the desired entry—that's terribly expensive and utterly defeats `HashMap`'s purpose: you may as well just hold a vector of `(key, val)` pairs!  Use [`HashMap::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) instead:

```
if let Some(value) = h.get_mut(input.as_str()) {
    ...
}
```

Next, one can insert into a vector without needing to explicitly resize it:

```
value.push(...);
```

Finally, what are we pushing onto the vector?  The type signature suggests string slices, `&str`, but these are mere borrows that have a limited life.  The `name` that we have read, however, will only exist in memory until the end of the scope in which it is declared (the `if` block) whereupon it will be dropped.  If you want to store borrows in the vector, then the underlying value must persist in memory for at least as long as the vector.

More likely you want to push *owned* string values, i.e. `String`, into the vector—but this would involve changing your type signature:

```
fn add_employee(h: &mut HashMap<&str, Vec<String>>) {
    println!("Choose a department:");
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    if let Some(value) = h.get_mut(input.as_str()) {
        println!("Enter a name to add to this department:");
        let mut name = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut name)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        value.push(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thank you very much I didn't know about the .get_mut() function! But the origin of this problem was because when I initialized my vector i thought that using only:  "" would be considered a string but actually it did consider it as a char so when i used .push() it told me a mismatch type error which i fixed using String::from("") while initializing the vector inside the hasmap. But your help was very appreciated mate!